# Sonarqube can't resolve issue

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-5.0

I'm using SonarQube 5.1 to analyse a C#/Typescript project.

All is working fine, except the issues seem to do what they want.
First, I have a much higher number of issues (4000) in the issue search, while the dashboard shows 1700 issues.

Furthermore, I can't close many issues, I get an error message like "Key '0d3d04ad-3684-4fde-8f02-535ad8b8b26d' not found". I deactivated several rules after issues have been found and the issues remained (I somehow expected them to be removed).

Even stranger is the fact, that the "issues" table in the SQL database had ~2200 entries. I don't get where the 4000 are coming from.

Is there any way to get rid of obsolete issues? (where rules are disabled)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the ElasticSearch index of issues is out of sync. This should be fixed by stopping the server, removing the `$SQ_HOME/data/es` folder and restarting the server.

Comment: That fixed it, thanks. Can I do something to prevent it going out of sync? And is there a WS call to reset the cache, restarting the server took ages after I removed the ES cache.

Comment: Going out of sync should not happen, but it is very hard to reproduce and people tend to notice it only when they don't have the analysis and server logs anymore. Unfortunately, there is no WS call to rebuild the ES index, and anyhow the server would display inconsistent data during the re-indexation.